# Malformed DNS Request Packet

Tags: tcp, dns, wireshark

I've been working on a project which involves sending `DNS` requests with information (not actual domains) in the questions (2 of them). I've been tracking the packets with `wireshark`.

Here is the `tcp` dump of the packet created.

> 00000000  00 02 01 00 00 02 00 00  00 00 00 00 01 32 03 65
>
> 00000010  6e 64 03 63 6f 6d 00 00  01 00 01 01 32 04 73 61
>
> 00000020  76 65 03 63 6f 6d 00 00  01 00 01
>
> ........ .....2.e
>
> nd.com.. ....2.sa
>
> ve.com.. ...

The `i.d.` and `qdcount` should be 2, recursion desired, and the domains shown are correct. `Wireshark` is saying that it is a malformed `DNS` packet. Any idea what is wrong with the packet?

Comment: Was this sent over UDP or TCP?  If it's sent over TCP, you need to precede the packet with a 2-byte length field giving the length of the DNS packet; see section 4.2.2 "TCP usage" in [RFC 1035](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1035).

Comment: It's supposed to be sent over UDP; however, I'm still fuzzy concerning the difference between UDP and TCP. To my understanding, TCP is used when the DNS packet is too big (>512 bytes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so:

- If you're doing the transport-layer networking yourself, your code will determine whether it's going over UDP or TCP, by specifying, when creating the socket on which to send the packet, whether it's a UDP or TCP socket;
- TCP is used if the packet won't fit in a maximum-sized UDP packet;
- if you're sending it over TCP, you need to precede it with a header, as per section 4.2.2 "TCP usage" in [RFC 1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035).

"Maximum-sized" is a bit vague.  [RFC 791](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791), the IPv4 specification, says, in section 3.1 "Internet Header Format":

```
Total Length:  16 bits

  Total Length is the length of the datagram, measured in octets,
  including internet header and data.  This field allows the length of
  a datagram to be up to 65,535 octets.  Such long datagrams are
  impractical for most hosts and networks.  All hosts must be prepared
  to accept datagrams of up to 576 octets (whether they arrive whole
  or in fragments).  It is recommended that hosts only send datagrams
  larger than 576 octets if they have assurance that the destination
  is prepared to accept the larger datagrams.

  The number 576 is selected to allow a reasonable sized data block to
  be transmitted in addition to the required header information.  For
  example, this size allows a data block of 512 octets plus 64 header
  octets to fit in a datagram.  The maximal internet header is 60
  octets, and a typical internet header is 20 octets, allowing a
  margin for headers of higher level protocols.
```

However, these days, the old networking hardware that would impose a maximum packet size limit as low as 576 bytes is mostly if not completely gone, and the real-world "maximum packet size" would generally be the Ethernet packet size - a total length of 1518 bytes, with 14 bytes of Ethernet header and 4 bytes of FCS, leaving 1500 bytes of payload.  For UDP, with a typical IPv4 header length of 20 bytes and a UDP header length of 8 bytes, that's 1472 bytes of data, so it's probably good enough to use TCP rather than UDP for DNS messages larger than 1472 bytes (IP fragmentation and reassembly will happen if any hop in the network route can't handle a 1500-byte IPv4 packet; that does increase the chances of the packet not getting through, as, if one fragment gets through but the other doesn't, the entire packet doesn't get through).

Comment: I'm using python and am sending the dns request with the python socket library. I would like to send it over UDP. In what function/which parameters would I do this?

Comment: Is it SOCK_DGRAM instead of SOCK_STREAM?

Comment: AF_INET/AF_INET6 + SOCK_DGRAM is the type of socket for UDP; AF_INET/AF_INET6 + SOCK_STREAM is the type of socket for TCP.

Comment: The minimum length of an IPv6 header is 80 bytes, so that's (1500-(80+8)) bytes of UDP payload = 1412 bytes of DNS (or other) protocol running on top of IPv6+UDP running on Ethernet.